# Unable to convert example of `useSwr` hook to use `react-query`'s `useMutation` hook?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, swr

I tried changing the `useSwr` hook to use:

```
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';

const { data: user, mutate: mutateUser } = useMutation<User>('/api/user');
```

But I get an error stating:

> No `mutationFn` found

Unable to solve this. I tried adding `mutationFn` inside `useMutation` like the following & it works but it is static:

```
const { data: user, mutate: mutateUser } = useMutation<User>('/api/user', {
    mutationFn: () => {
      const u: User = {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        avatarUrl: '',
        login: '',
      }
      return Promise.resolve(u)
    },
  })
```

If I use a dynamic request using something like `axios` then do I need to put the `fetchJson` from `login.tsx` to `mutationFn` hook?

Basically, I want to use `react-query` instead of `swr` & `ky` instead of `fetchJson` & unable to find a solution?

I'm pretty sure it's really simple but haven't been able to make it work.

Stackblitz Demo → https://stackblitz.com/edit/next-iron-session-with-react-query?file=lib%2FuseUser.ts (go to `/login` route, enter a github username like `vvo` & click `Login` to see the error in console)

Repo → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-iron-session-with-react-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By navigating through the documentation it seems that the first argument of the `useMutation` if the `mutationFn` and not the `mutationKey`

[useMutation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useMutation)

What if the code changes to:

```js
const { data: user, mutate: mutateUser } = useMutation<User, unknown, { username: string }>((body) => {
      return fetchJson('/api/login', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
       body: JSON.stringify(body),
      })
    }, {
      mutationKey: '/api/user'
    }
  })
```

and when you need to actually mutate

```
mutateUser({ username: 'Username' })
```

Comment: naah, the above code where i wrote `Promise.resolve` is right. i checked it works. it redirects when i used `loggedIn: true`. i'm asking how do i send `username` in `login.tsx` on line no. 25 → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-iron-session-with-react-query/blob/master/pages/login.tsx#L25? all i want is the logic for auth remains in one place, specifically, the `useUser` hook.

Comment: just edited the question to make it clear that the 2nd code block works :)

Comment: basically, my question is what should i put in `mutationFn` because there is no equivalent of it in `swr` so i'm confused what to actually put in there? empty function doesn't work.

Comment: got it, I've just updated the answer to match with what you're looking for. This way when you invoke the mutation callback you can send from outside the body and keep the logic hidden in the `useUser` hook

Comment: that is exactly what i want to do but i get 1 last error: `Argument of type '{ username: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.ts(2345)` on the last block of code `mutateUser`. if i solve this, then everything works, thanks!

Comment: In this case, `useMutation` is already prepared to receive a generic that specifies the parameter of the mutator function. Gonna update the answer to include it as well

Comment: wow, thank you so much. this was pita for too long :)